# Separating SAS from SATA drives

Tags: centos, hard-disk, disk, sata

I have to list all SAS drives and separately list all SATA drives, I'm working on CentOS6 and tried lots of commands which will give some specific information about bus of disks.
Let me show you example outputs on two different servers by using ***lshw -businfo -class disk***
:
[image]

[image]

As you can see I can't differ SATA from SAS
Does someone have an idea how can I check whether disk is SATA or SAS?
Thank you